# Do I need to use encryption in my android app

Tags: c#, encryption, google-play

I have been thinking of releasing an Android App to the Google Play Store however the app does not use encryption for web requests, it does not transmit any personal details over the web, is HTTP okay or will Google reject it?

edit: I have attempted to get in contact with Google however their either closed or too busy.

edit 2: Some have been asking for detail so I will provide that, All I will be requesting is the current temperature from an API which does not require a certificate.

Comment: You should absolutely be using https for all web traffic these days.

Comment: I am completely new to Android development and I am only just understanding web requests. I am in no way capable of making HTTPS requests.

Comment: Depending the details (which you haven't provided) making an HTTPS web request can be as simple as replacing `http://` in the URL with `https://`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google will accept it for now, but this could change very soon.